# Why doesn't imported class attribute change in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to understand the mechanism of `__import__(fromlist=['MyClass'])`.
Imagine I have several classes `WhiteBox`:

```
class WhiteBox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "White Box"
        self.color = None

    def use(self, color):
        self.paint(color)

    def paint(self, color):
        self.color = color
```

I am importing these *classes* with `__import__(fromlist=['WhiteBox'])` statement.
I decide to repaint all boxes with the same color and create a loop:

```
for box in imported_boxes:
    box.WhiteBox().use = "green"
    print("REPAINTED:", box.WhiteBox().name, box.WhiteBox().color)
```

When I try to access `box.WhiteBox().color` attribute, I still get `None`.

```
REPAINTED: WhiteBox None
```

I expected that `__import__` would allow to manipulate the object as if it was instantiated, it appears not true. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you should add `self.color = None` into `__init__` function

Comment: sorry, was too quick, ok. If I add `self.color = None`, the attribute will stay `None`.

Comment: It should change when you call  `box.WhiteBox().use = "green"` , didnt it?

Comment: Yeah and change `use` function as yoav says

Comment: If there is only one color for whole objects of `WhiteBox` make color a `static class variable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use are using "use" as a property but it it defined as a function:

```
box = box.WhiteBox() = "green"
#change it to:
box.WhiteBox().use("green")
```

Next problem:

You are creating WhiteBox again and again so it will always have the initial None Value...

```
box.WhiteBox().use("green") #created once
print("REPAINTED:", box.WhiteBox().name, box.WhiteBox().color) #two more times...
```